# Custom route module not working anymore

Tags: module, router

I'm trying a page from a custom module, but the magento is showing me this message

> The URL you request is not accessible.

This url is (usually) reachable, I made it over a year ago and didn't change anything in that module.

The weirdest, is that I've made a copy of the website 2 days ago (the problem is here since about 7 days), and I can't reproduce the bug on my dump the url is reachable...

I'm on Magento 2.2.4, and I can't easily rebuild the website on production...

Comment: I know this might sound stupid: check that the module is enabled. It you're 100% sure your code is the same, it might be a php version difference between your environments. It's complicated to know.

Comment: Ah ah, doesn't sound stupid ! But the module is enable. Version PHP 7.1.18 & 7.1.33, but I don't think this is a big deal

Comment: this in only this route, the other route from the same module are working well